# Custom kernel 2.6.18 compile in centos ends on fail

Tags: centos, kernel, compile, rpm, make

I'm compiling from RPM source. The same compile worked in the past but not this time.

May be you can help me to solve this issue?

```
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/rpmbuild/BUILD/kernel-2.6.18/xen/arch/x86'
gzip -f -9 < /root/rpmbuild/BUILD/kernel-2.6.18/xen/xen > /root/rpmbuild/BUILD/kernel-2.6.18/xen/xen.gz.new
mv /root/rpmbuild/BUILD/kernel-2.6.18/xen/xen.gz.new /root/rpmbuild/BUILD/kernel-2.6.18/xen/xen.gz
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/rpmbuild/BUILD/kernel-2.6.18/xen'
BUILDING A KERNEL FOR x86_64...
USING ARCH=x86_64
***
*** You have not yet configured your kernel!
***
*** Please run some configurator (e.g. "make oldconfig" or
*** "make menuconfig" or "make xconfig").
***

RPM build errors:
```

Thanks

Comment: May I ask why you are dealing with such an old kernel?

Comment: 2.6.18 is the default kernel for CentOS 5. Why is OP using CentOS 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cd /root/rpmbuild/BUILD/kernel-2.6.18/xen/arch/x86
cp configs/<desired-config-file> .config
make oldconfig
make menuconfig
```

or

```
make xconfig
```

Then

```
cp .config ~/rpmbuild/SOURCES/config-`uname -m`-generic
cd /root/rpmbuild
rpmbuild -bb --target=`uname -m` kernel.spec
```